# Node.js: How to prevent the next line execution until my forLoop gives me result

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

```
let a = []
    for (let i=0;i<4;i++){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            a.push(i);
        },2000)
    }


console.log(a);
```

Here I am getting a always blank []. Please suggest a way to stop executing console.log(a) line until a gets filled.

Comment: The code example is trying to mix asynchronous and synchronous coding techniques, which _does not work_.  Using the search box to search for "aynchronous for loop" returns 907 questions, some with multiple answers. Refining the search with details of your actual use case may help reduce the number of hits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You should await `setTimeout`:

```js
let a = [];
async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        a.push(i);
        resolve();
      }, 2000)
    );
  }
}

await test();

console.log(a);
```

Note: You can also use `Promise.allSettled` to run them at the same time